# Mock device location on release mode

Tags: android, permissions, android-manifest

Is it possible to mock the device locatio in release mode?
When I am trying to put the permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
```

It writes me an error:

```
Mock locations should only be requested in  test or a debug-specific manifest file.
```

And I can't run the project.

Is it possible to do it in release mode?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a code error, it is a Lint error. You can always reduce the severity of the error from error to warning in the Lint settings, which will still give you the warning, but no longer prevent your app from running.

As a general rule, you don't want to leave this permission in the release versions, as it may allow users to spoof their location, resulting in your app doing things it shouldn't be doing out in the wild.

Comment: hi, i would like to get your attention to this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35539960/how-to-get-release-build-apk-file-using-proguard, your help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In your app level build.gradle file where you add dependencies, please add these lines

```
android{
......
lintOptions{
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
.....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In AndroidManifest.xml you have to add:

**xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"** in header, then in tag permission MOCK_LCATION add **tools:ignore="MockLocation"**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"
        tools:ignore="MockLocation" />

//....
/>
```